# Detect when USB device detached from Android device

Tags: android, usb

I am using a usb POS printer with my application.  I have successfully written the code to connect, request permission and print data.  However, I'm unsure how do notify the user when the printer is disconnected, if it is then the device falls back to the network printer.

So this is my BroadcastReceiver for requesting permission:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(device != null){
                        mDevice = device;

                        if(mConnection == null){
                            Log.i(m_Tag, "Connection is null");
                        }
                        Log.i(m_Tag, "Connected successfully");
                    }else{
                        Log.i(m_Tag, "Device is null");
                    }
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I have trawled through the forums here and suggested answers and I've checked out this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html  I can't find a solid way to do it without including a device filter xml file.  I can't do this because I'm unsure as to what model of printer will be used by the end user.

My brain is fried from this, if someone could please point out how to do this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late, but for future readers here is how I do it.

In `onStart()` I register a broadcast receiver for the `ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` action.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");
        super.onStart();

        // Catch a USB detach broadcast intent.
        detachReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if(intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
                    jobsDone();
                }
            }
        };

        // Set the intent filter for the broadcast receiver, and register.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        registerReceiver(detachReceiver, filter);
}
```

In my `jobsDone()` I just finish the Activity which is basically the same as pressing "back".

```
private void jobsDone() {
    Log.d(TAG, "jobsDone()");
    this.finish();
}
```

Since in my case only one USB device can be attached at one single time I do not have to bother with `device_filter.xml` for the detach.

Also remember to unregister the receiver.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop()");
    super.onStop();
    // Unregister the BroadcastReceiver
    unregisterReceiver(detachReceiver);
}
```

Comment: i tried broadcast receiver for device detach, unfortunately it triggers only when i attach the device back.